# Compiling YAML with ERB and Rails path helpers mixed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a navigation helper in my application that compiles the page navigation for the current namespace/controller from a YAML file. My YAML is something like this:

```
---
manage:
  - link: <%= manage_clients_path %>
    icon: torsos-all
    label: Clients
  - link: <%= manage_users_path %>
    icon: torso
    label: Users
```

In my helper, I've gone through a couple iterations, but right now I'm with this code:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'
module NavigationHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def navigation
    unless current_user.nil?
      namepsace = params[:controller].split('/').first
      compiledNav = ERB.new File.read(File.join Rails.root, 'config/navigation.yml')
      nav = YAML.load compiledNav.result
      if nav.has_key?(namepsace) && !nav[namespace].blank?
        nav[namepsace]
      else
        []
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Right now, I get an error that manage_clients_path is not defined (`undefined local variable or method`manage_clients_path' for main:Object`), but I can guarentee that it does exist by running`rake routes`.

From `rake routes`

```
$ ./bin/spring rake routes | grep manage_clients
manage_clients    GET    /manage/clients(.:format)    manage/clients#index
```

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes` output,so that making sure `manage_clients_path` exists?

Comment: @Pavan, I added only the relevant line from rake routes to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After even further testing, I found the issue was slightly different. After converting things to HAML we still ended up with nils when using the url helpers. This is the code that I ended with that worked:

YAML:

```
manage:
  - link: <%= manage_clients_path %>
    icon: torsos-all
    label: Clients
  - link: <%= manage_users_path %>
    icon: torso
    label: Users
```

*Note the missing `---` at the top. Not sure if that effects things or not.*

Ruby:

```
require 'yaml'

module NavigationHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def navigation
    unless current_user.nil?
      namepsace = params[:controller].split('/').first
      nav = YAML.load(
        ERB.new(
          File.read(File.join Rails.root, 'config/navigation.yml')
        ).result(binding)
      )
      if nav.has_key?(namepsace) && !nav[namespace].blank?
        nav[namepsace]
      else
        []
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It seems that including the URL Helpers and binding the ERB cimpiler to the NavigationHelper is what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be caused by my use of HAML to build my views and layouts. I changed the code to the following and everything works:

YAML config:

```
---
manage:
  - link: #{manage_clients_path}
    icon: torsos-all
    label: Clients
  - link: #{manage_users_path}
    icon: torso
    label: Users
```

And my helper:

```
require 'yaml'

module NavigationHelper
  def navigation
    unless current_user.nil?
      namepsace = params[:controller].split('/').first
      nav = YAML.load_file File.join(Rails.root, 'config/navigation.yml')
      if nav.has_key?(namepsace) && !nav[namespace].blank?
        nav[namepsace]
      else
        []
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now everything is working.